# how to add to the x bounds of a jlabel upon button press

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, bounds

What I want to accomplish is simple, I press a JButton (called 'right') and the x bounds of a JLabel is increased by 100, effectively moving the JLabel 100 pixels to the right. I have been experimenting with stuff such as :

```
        if(clicked == right) {
            piece.getBounds().x = +100;
        }
```

and I tried :

```
        if(clicked == right) {
            piece.addBounds(100,0,0,0);
        }
```

the method addBounds was undefined for type JLabel
so I tried :

```
        if(clicked == right) {
            piece.setBounds(+100,0,0,0);
        }
```

and clearly all of the above didn't work, but were worth the try. Is there a way to do what I'm tried to do?

Comment: It seems this might be better achieved by changing the values of an `EmptyBorder` applied to a single label, or by abandoning using a component completely and doing custom painting of a string or image. What is the ultimate purpose of all this 'moving a label'? See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: What's the `LayoutManager` of the component the label lives in? A minimal, complete example would help to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The bounds are actually a Rectangle, and so you can get the JLabel's Bounds, advance its x position, and then set the bounds by calling the appropriate methods:

```
Rectangle bounds = piece.getBounds();  // get the bounds
bounds.x += 100;    // increment the x value
piece.setBounds(bounds);   // re-set the new bounds

repaint();   // call repaint on the container that holds the JLabel so it is repainted
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know much about java yet, still learning, appreciate your response!

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the swing components in Java are required to be repainted when a change is made to them.

Try simply calling the "repaint()" method when the button has been pressed and your changes to the component should update.